# ASP.net MVC Web Host for growth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, web-hosting

Need to find a web host for our ASP.net MVC website (Hooked to an SQL Database). To start with the traffic will be quite low but the room for growth could be huge so we need a web host that can dynamically grow if needed to take the traffic influx.

Does anyone have any advice or know of any host solutions for this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: "SQL Database" confirm: MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

what about windows azure?

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 scales on demand